# Dynamic invocation (or emulation) of the hierarchy custom setting getInstance() method

Tags: dynamic-soql, customsetting

I have a requirement to avoid any compile-time dependency on a managed package. Dynamic SOQL, SObjectType and SObject allow me to do this cleanly for normal objects.

But now I need to access a public hierarchy custom setting from the managed package. With compile-time dependency this would work:

```
ns__CustomSetting__c setting = ns__CustomSetting__c.getInstance();
```

But there does not appear to be a dynamic alternative API; methods like `getInstance()` are not present on SObject. Or have I missed something?

Is the only approach available to use dynamic SOQL to query the various rows of the hierarchy and emulate the semantics of `getInstance()` in Apex code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access custom settings dynamically through a query. Unfortunately, this means that you'll have to burn a query and at least one query row (and up to 3). First, you'll get the user's organization ID, profile ID, and user ID, then perform a query like: `SELECT Id, SetupOwnerId FROM CustomSetting__c WHERE SetupOwnerId IN (:userId, :profileId, :orgId)`. Then, you have to go through each field of each returned row (if any), and override higher level settings with lower level settings.

```
Map<SObjectType, Setting__c> settings = new Map<SobjectType, Setting__c>();
for(Setting__c record: [SELECT Id, SetupOwnerId... FROM Setting__c WHERE ...])
    settings.put(record.setupownerid.getsobjecttype(), record);

if(settings.containskey(organization.sobjecttype)) {
    ...
}
if(settings.containskey(profile.sobjecttype)) {
    ...
}
if(settings.containskey(user.sobjecttype)) {
    ...
}
```

There's no other way to access those settings. Also, you can't access protected settings outside the package.

Comment: Clarification: I think that you meant `if(settings.containskey(profile.sobjecttype)) {` on line 8

Comment: I did. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Though we can dynamically get custom settings records by a dynamic query

```
Database.query('SELECT Id, SetupOwnerId FROM ' + x + ' WHERE SetupOwnerId IN (\'' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '\',\'' + UserInfo.getProfileId() + '\',\'' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId() + '\')')
```

were `x` is the name of custom settings, like `Hierarchy_Custom_Setting__c`,  I think we should instead open an idea for Salesforce to implement an appropriate method for that like this one https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZREQA4 and we should vote for it to be able to get Hierarchy custom settings records dynamically without burning SOQL query

Comment: In my experience developer oriented ideas don't get implemented so possibly wasted effort.

Comment: @KeithC At least we can call schema method to get record type id by Developername, this is something. Except for this rare case exception I totally agree with you but we shouldn't give up.