# Custom Settings are NO SObjects - How to use them polymorphic?

Tags: apex, customsetting, polymorphism

My app uses different types of custom settings. Let's call them SettingA__c and SettingC_c.

I want a method that handles both types of settings polymorphically.

```
private void handle(SObject setting) {
   String name = (String) setting.get('Name');

   if(setting.getValues(name) != null) {
      doSomethingWith(setting);
   }
}
```

This is not possible as `getValues()` is undefined on `SObject` and I could not find a common base object for Custom Settings in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question and answer [Dynamic invocation (or emulation) of the hierarchy custom setting getInstance() method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23786/dynamic-invocation-or-emulation-of-the-hierarchy-custom-setting-getinstance) are related. The solution there is to use SOQL to access the custom setting (impacting the SOQL governor limit) and then you can use the normal dynamic SOQL methods on the result.

It sounds like you are using list custom settings not hierarchical ones so your query can be simpler and pretty much like querying a normal SObject.

Comment: Do keep in mind that soql on custom settings does not leverage cache, which could be part of why you're using custom settings.

Comment: You also lose the intelligent hierarchical defaulting for hierarchical settings by doing this, but there's no other way of doing it dynamically.